# Возможно ли с использованием sql посчитать кол-во совпадении элементов по столбцам?

Tags: sql

Возможно ли с использованием `sql` посчитать кол-во совпадении элементов по столбцам. Нужно найти кол-во совпадений элементов из первого столбца во втором и сумму занести в третий. Примерно должно выглядеть так:

```
столбец 1         столбец 2        совпадений
2                 2                2
3                 2                1
4                 3                0
1                 1                1
```

Comment: Исправьте отображение примера, оформите в виде 'кода'

Comment: Почему `3 - 2 -> 1`? элементы ведь не совпали?

Comment: @PashaPash, потому что число 3 во втором столбце встречается 1 раз. Т.е. столбец 2 в результате для красоты присутствует.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или так:

```
select t1.col1, count(t2.col2) matches
from tablo t1 
  left join tablo t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
group by t1.col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
    select [столбец 1], 
           [столбец 2], 
           (select count(*) from Table where [столбец 2] = t.[столбец 1]) as [count]
    from Table t
```